# Howto add documentation comment in PyCharm IDE

Tags: documentation, comments, pycharm

In PhpStorm you can write `/**` before any function/method/class and after pressing enter key and you will get autocompleted doc comment, that contain params, exception and return statements.
Similar functionality exists in PyCharm? I have tried to write `'''` but it's don't work for me.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/creating-documentation-comments.html

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (activate intention action), **Insert documentation string stub**.

Answer (score 4):

After typing the function heading (e.g., def myfunc(...)) and the following colon (:) press enter, then type """ (3 double-quotes), and press enter again.